# funcion en viewmodel con kotlin

Tags: kotlin

hola antes que nada aclaro tengo apenas 4 meses investigando el mundo jetpack compose en android con kotlin  y arme la app viendo videos e investigando por mi cuenta, asi que seguro habrá cosas raras o mal aplicadas para uds en el codigo. Espero puedan entenderme.

Tengo esta funcion leerRutas en mi viewModel, la cual lee los registros de mi base da datos segun la ruta seleccionada de un drawercontent. funciona bien, excepto cuando cambia de ruta, pasa dos veces por un lugar que supuestamente no deberia pasar. Este es parte de mi viewModel

viewMmodel..

```
 private val _conexiones = mutableStateOf(ListState()) // listState es de tipo  List<Int> 

 private val conexiones : State<ListState> = _conexiones  

// declaro la variable para ver si tengo q leer o no la ruta

var readRoutes =  mutableStateOf(true)

//var readRoutes =  true // antes la declare asi y nada, no se cual de las dos formas es la correcta

fun leerRuta() {
        if (readRoutes.value) {  //si es true ejecuto este codigo para leer la ruta

            readRoutes.value = false  // pongo la variable en false
            _conexiones.value = conexiones.value.copy(conexionesList = emptyList())  // borro la lista 


            getConexiones(G_currentRoute).onEach { conex_id ->   // esta funcion getConexiones lee el campo conexionId  desde la base de datos y la carga a la lista

                _conexiones.value = conexiones.value.copy(conexionesList = conex_id)



                if (_conexiones.value.conexionesList.isNotEmpty()) {
                    _conexiones.value.conexionesList.first()  // si la lista no esta vacia me posiciono en el primer registsro de la lista

                    if (G_conexionId == 0) {   // otra var global q uso en otro lado , lei q no es aconsejable pero no pude evitar usar variables globales por mi poco conocimiento
                        G_possitionList = 0  // inicializo una variable global para llevar el control de la posicion en que estoy en la lista, porque luego me desplazo por ella
                    }

                    currentId = _conexiones.value.conexionesList[G_possitionList]  //obtengo el valor de esa lista segun su posicion
                    wasUpdated = true  // variable para actualizar otras variables

//  Aqui tengo el problema, con la funcion getlectura de abajo obtengo el valor del registro completo de la base de datos y actualizo las variables. El problema que tengo que al cambiar de ruta y actualizar las variables vuelve a a entrar a este punto y me trae el registro anterior. 
no me respeta la linea inicial de ... if (readRoutes.value) ... es como que se queda en este bloque y ejecuta esta parte de codigo sin salir de la funcion. no entiendo el comportamiento en esta parte

                    viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
                        getLectura(currentId)?.also { registro ->
                            updateVariables(registro)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }.launchIn(viewModelScope)


          

        }
    }
```

por otro lado no me queda claro la diferencia entre
`viewModelScope.launch {....`  y  `.... }.launchIn(viewModelScope)`

muchas gracias desde ya por su tiempo

Comment: El tema es... ¿dónde tienes definido getConexiones? ¿No deberías tener únicamente una conexión en un momento dado, también al cambiar de ruta?

Comment: gracias ya pude resolverle, estaba usando en mi dao la sgte linea .........  
       
    //fun  getConexiones(ruta: String): Flow<List<Int>>           la cambie por  ...... suspend fun getConexiones(ruta: String): List<Int> y ahora me funciona.

Comment: no me queda claro aun la diferencia entre usar viewModelScope.launch { lineas de codigo}  y .{lineas de codigo  y al final}.launchIn(viewModelScope)